# Create new sObject on parent object in for loop

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I have the following data model -
Accounts can have multiple Contracts
Contracts have Billing_Unit__c and Cases generated on actions from external app

I want to loop through all my Billing_Unit__c and if the conditions are filled, create a case related to the Contract and Account (and check it once per day using Schedulable Apex). Here is the code I have:

```
global class CaseGenerator implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        createInvoiceCase();
    }
    public void createInvoiceCase() {
     List<Billing_Unit__c> invoiceCases = new List<Billing_Unit__c>();
     invoiceCases = [SELECT Id, Contract__r.Id
                                  FROM Billing_Unit__c
                                  WHERE Invoicing_Date__c = TODAY AND
                                  Unlimited__c = TRUE];
    for(Billing_Unit__c bgut : invoiceCases) {
        // create case related to Contract__r.id here
        // Case cseobj = new Case (subject= 'Send Invoice'; Contract__c=Contract__r) (???)
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated! thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close as-is.

You don't really need to query `Contract__r.Id` (`Contract__c` will suffice).
It helps if you understand what the `__c` and `__r` "fields" are, and the difference between them.

### Some helpful background

When you have a lookup (or a master-detail relationship, or one of the funky standard relationships), let's just call the field `lookup__c`, the `__c` field contains the Id of the "parent" record. In page layouts, and anytime you use something like `<apex:inputField>`, Salesforce does some magic to display the name of the related record...but in the back-end the field really stores an Id.

When you query for `lookup__r`, what you get back is actually an `SObject`. It'll only contain the fields on the parent object that you explicitly queried, but it is a proper `SObject` instance.

### On to your actual question

The most common way to relate an SObject record to another record is to set the relationship field(s) to an Id. Since you're already using the SObject constructor to populate fields, I'll just continue with that.

You can use `Contract__r.Id`, but in the end it's probably easier (and a little less typing) to just use `Contract__c`

```
invoiceCases = [SELECT Id, Contract__c
                              FROM Billing_Unit__c
                              WHERE Invoicing_Date__c = TODAY AND
                              Unlimited__c = TRUE];
for(Billing_Unit__c bgut : invoiceCases) {
    // create case related to Contract__r.id here
    // When using the SObject constructor to populate fields, the expressions 
    //   that you use to set the field value aren't terminated with a semicolon.
    // Instead, just use a comma to move on to the next field, or use a close
    //   parenthesis if that was the last field.
    Case cseobj = new Case(
        subject= 'Send Invoice',
        Contract__c= bgut.Contract__c,
        // The API name of the relationship field between Contact and Account is
        //   'AccountId' (a standard field, so no __c)
        AccountId = /*query the AccountId from your Contract, and use that here*/
    );
}
```